# Capybara: webkit and selenium can't find url, racktest works

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, capybara, capybara-webkit

Multi domain app. Using POW server locally. Cucumber tests

In one of the steps i set app_host (subdomain belongs to account and fabricated each time):

```
def set_current_subdomain(subdomain)
  Capybara.app_host = "http://#{subdomain}.example.com:#{Capybara.server_port}"
end
```

in cucumber settings:

```
Capybara.run_server = true 
Capybara.server_port = 8200
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium #default driver when you using @javascript tag
Capybara.app = Rack::ShowExceptions.new(MyApp::Application)
Capybara.default_driver = :rack_test
```

Step example

```
visit(new_user_session_url(subdomain: @account.subdomain, port: Capybara.server_port))
```

Cucumber tests pass with :rack_test but not with :webkit or :selenium

```
Unable to load URL: http://veumbogan8d11d7feca.example.com:8200/signin because of error loading http://veumbogan8d11d7feca.example.com:8200/signin: Unknown error (Capybara::Webkit::InvalidResponseError)
```

webkit_debug output:

```
Finished "EnableLogging" with response "Success()" 
Wrote response true "" 
Received "Visit" 
Started "Visit" 
Load started 
"Visit" started page load 
Started request to "http://kuphal375cb65167.example.com:8200/signin" 
Finished "Visit" with response "Success()" 
Received 0 from "http://kuphal375cb65167.example.com:8200/signin" 
Page finished with false 
Load finished 
Page load from command finished 
Wrote response false "{"class":"InvalidResponseError","message":"Unable to load URL: http://kuphal375cb65167.example.com:8200/signin because of error loading http://kuphal375cb65167.example.com:8200/signin: Unknown error"}"
```

When using selenium, firefox opens with "Server not found"

Nothing suspicious in test.log: account was created, notification email has been sent, etc

- rails 3.2.17
- mongoid 2.4.11
- capybara 2.1.0
- webkit 1.1.1
- selenium-webdriver 2.40.0

Would appreciate an advice how to debug this and what might be the problem

PS: database_cleaner setup:

```
require 'database_cleaner'
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
DatabaseCleaner.orm = "mongoid"
Before { DatabaseCleaner.clean }
```